# Get Variable From Controller To View

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in PHP and learning codeignitor. I have controller where function like below

```
 public function view($user_id){
        $data = array();

        if(!empty($user_id)){
            $data['member'] = $this->member->getRows(array('user_id' => $user_id));

            $fstatus = 'Member Details';

            $getfriend = $this->member->getfriend($user_id);
            if($getfriend){
                $data['fstatus']  = 'true';
            }
            else{
               $data['fstatus']  = 'false';
            }

            $this->load->view('members/view', $data);

        }else{
            redirect('members');
        }
    }
```

Its working fine for get data in my view using code like

```
echo $member['fistname'];
```

But I am not able to access data called `$member['fstatus']` in view. which I am defining in controller with below

```
$fstatus = 'Member Details';
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can solve it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define this variable as an data array element and also recieve it as a data array element.

```
$data['fsstatus'] = 'something'; //define

echo $fsstatus; // show
```

Comment: Yes, this is working fine! I will accept this as answer. Thanks!